# Compare Cells between two DataGridViews

Tags: c#

Good Day,

I want to compare cells between two DataGridviews and mark the respective cells that are different in my source DataGridView (GridView1 below). At the moment, I can only compare rows. Is it possible for me to compare the DataGridViews cell by respective cell and mark only the cells with differences?

Here is an example:
Table 1:
**3**       6         **8**

Table 2:
**2**      6         5

```
private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable src1 = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    DataTable src2 = dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable;
    int index1 = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row1 in src1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row2 in src2.Rows)
        {
            int index2 = 0;
            bool duplicateRow = true;
            for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row1.ItemArray.Count(); cellIndex++)
            {
                if (!row1.ItemArray[cellIndex].Equals(row2.ItemArray[cellIndex].ToString()))
                {
                    duplicateRow = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (duplicateRow)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red; 
            }

            index2++;
        }
        index1++;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to mark all the cells in gridview1 that are not present in gridview2. Is that right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataTable src1 = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
DataTable src2 = dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable;
```

If the two gridview have the same number of column and row :

```
for(int i=0; i<src1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row1 = src1.Rows[i].ItemArray;
    var row2 = src2.Rows[i].ItemArray;

    for(int j = 0; j < row1.Length; j++)
    {
        if (!row1[j].ToString().Equals(row2[j].ToString()))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red; 
            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please help me in my issue how to compare 2 grid cell values and insert only in case of not equals       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72532790/how-to-compare-data-from-2-datagridview-cells    thank you in advance